# Azure Devops: How to restricts users from creating feature branch from development branch?

Tags: git, azure-devops

We have 3 major branches in our project "master", "development" and "qa". we want that only admins should be allowed to create feature branch from development and qa branches. All users should be able to create feature branches from master branch.

I am new to azure devops. I tried changing the user permission from build security of a branch but user was not listed in the search.

Comment: That's not really how Git works. You can control where changes are *merged* from (via branch policies). Branches are just pointers to commits. Several branches can point to the *same* commit at once. What is the problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @DanielMann Thanks for your answer. I am new to devops. We have 3 major branches in a Repo. Master, Dev and Qa. Right now we have following process in place:
1. Create Feature branch from Master branch. 
2. Then, Merge feature branch into dev and qa branch. 
3. Merge qa into Master branch.
Sometimes, developers directly create feature branches from dev or qa. This is something my boss want me to restrict. So that developers should not be able to create branch from dev or qa branches.

Comment: Branching per environment in Git is a *really* bad idea. Look at adopting the GitFlow or GitHubFlow branching models, as they are more suited for the particulars of Git's paradigm for version control.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMann I will look into the suggested models.

Comment: Note you didn't actually answer "What is the problem you're trying to solve here?". You said you want to restrict developers from branching off of `development` because your boss wants to restrict it. But why does your boss want to restrict it? (What problem occurs by allowing it, which doesn't occur if you prevent it?) Side Note: by restricting it, sometimes you might have conflicts when merging a feature that came off of `master` into `development`, and the two ways to resolve that conflict both involve bringing the commits from `development` into the feature branch...